# Don't know how to build task 'weeklydelete'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I'm trying to setup [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#defining-tasks) with my cron_job task and I'm getting the following error when running heroku run rake weeklydelete:

```
Don't know how to build task 'weeklydelete'
```

My task code looks like this:

```
task :weeklydelete do
  set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
  job_type :script, "'#{path}/script/:task' :output"

  every :sunday, at: "3:00 AM" do
  runner "Event.clear_expired"
  runner "Activity.clear_expired"
  end

end
```

Essentially, I want to delete Events and Activities that are a week old - every Sunday.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update: # lib/tasks/deletion.rb**

```
namespace :deletion do
  desc :weekly_delete => :environment do
    set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
    job_type :script, "'#{path}/script/:task' :output"

    every :sunday, at: "3:00 AM" do
    runner "Event.clear_expired"
    runner "Activity.clear_expired"
  end
 end
end
```

and in console called:

```
heroku run deletion:weekly_delete -a appname
```

error:

```
Running `rake weekly_delete` attached to terminal... up, run.4492
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'weekly_delete'
```

Comment: Usually means rake can't find the task that. Run in wrong folder, wrong namespace or wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be like this:

```
# lib/tasks/deletion.rb
namespace :deletion do
  desc :weekly_delete => :environment do
    # ...
  end
end
```

and you call it like this:

```
$ rake deletion:weekly_delete
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. Check out the updated code above, what am I doing wrong? Cheers

Comment: As I'm demonstrating in the above example, you have to do `heroku run rake deletion:weekly_delete`

Comment: OIC, but it's still not working....Running `rake deletion:weekly_delete` attached to terminal... up, run.8619
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deletion:weekly_delete'

Comment: What is the actual path of the file?

Comment: The actual; path is lib/tasks/deletion.rb

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the file from deletion.rb to deletion.rake